# Почему не отображается цвет?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, notepad++

Шрифт поменялся на Arial, но цвет почему-то на веб-странице не отображается. Как это исправить? И ещё вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы в notepad++ подсвечивались два синтаксиса: html и css?

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <style type="text/css">
   body {
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: dark blue;
    h1:{
     font-family: arial;
     color: red;
    }
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Всем привет!</h1>
  <p>Мой любимый язык программирования - C++.
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Павел Варшавский не помогло, всё равно цвета не отображаются

Comment: У меня не работает :(

Comment: В смысле? В чём ошибка?

Comment: Я смотрю. Вижу, что всё работает на codepen. У меня не работает. Вы сказали, что у меня синтаксическая ошибка. В чём заключается ошибка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это правильно

```css
body {
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: darkblue;
    }
    h1{
     font-family: arial;
     color: red;
    }
```

Вот так нет

нету такого цвета : dark blue есть darkblue

```css
   body {
    font-family: arial;
    background-color: dark blue; /*не закрыт body*/
    h1:{
     font-family: arial;
     color: red;
    }
   }
```

Comment: Ааа... Я понял! Спасибо! А Вы не знаете как сделать так, чтобы в notepad++ подсвечивались сразу синтаксисы html и css в одном файле?

Comment: я знаю что писать надо css отдельно от html

Comment: SublimeText так может подсвечивать разные синтаксисы, а notepad++ этого не может делать.